# Why can't I extract file URLs using contentsOfDirectory when using an ios simulator?

Tags: swift, ios-simulator, swift5, nsfilemanager

I'm having trouble trying to understand how file url access works in swift. I know that FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask) always produces a unique url for every application launch. AFAIK accessing security scoped resource allows me to access the contents of the files in that url. However, even after doing that, I can't return any files in the document directory using contentsOfDirectory. I tried to see if that directory was empty by trying to add some custom files in there from my macbook, but an error message stated that files of the same name were already there. If those files are already there (btw in every unique url), why aren't their urls being returned by contentsOfDirectory? Is there a way I can extract an array of file urls from an iphone simulator or is it just that this method doesn't work in a simulator?

```
let document_files: [String] = ["/Users/james/Documents/Apple_Developer_Program_License_Agreement_XV2A27GUJ6.pdf", "/Users/james/Documents/BH_US_11_Sullivan_Server_Side_WP.pdf", "/Users/james/Documents/Classical and Quantum Singularities of Levi-Civita Spacetimes.pdf"]

let currentURL: URL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

guard currentURL.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() else {
    return nil
}

for document_file in document_files {
    do {
        try fileManager.copyItem(atPath: document_file, toPath: currentURL.path)
        //MARK: - When I do this, the system says the file already exists at FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

let files = try? fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: currentURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: [kCFURLNameKey as URLResourceKey], options: .includesDirectoriesPostOrder)
        //MARK: - But after this line, files array is still empty?
        //In the main app, fileExists was used on a new mac url created by combining the last component of user selection url with my custom mac url.

if files != nil {
    print("files is at least not nil.")
    if files!.count > 0 {
        //MARK: - This loop was thus never executed.
        for file in files! {
            print("File!")
            print(file)
            //Contents is my custom array.
            contents.append(file)
        }
    }
    else {
        print("However, files is empty.")
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to replace the documen directory with a file?  It doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can NOT copy a file from the macOS user documents into your app document directory. Second mistake is that your are repeatedly trying to replace a directory with your files (which you can't read from your iOS app). Your files don't exist at the destination, what exists there is your app document directory, you were supposed to append the file name to the destination directory URL. The `contentsOfDirectory` method doesn't return any file because the directory is empty. Note also that `contentsOfDirectory` performs a shallow enumeration and the only supported option is `skipsHiddenFiles`. You can not manually add a file to your app documents directory but you can include them in your bundle and after launching your app you can copy them there.

Comment: Thank you Leo. I want to make a file scraper (i.e. a function that returns all the pdf urls in the files folder for an ios device). Then will contentsOfDirectory work when a user manually adds a file to the files app? I'm basically trying to find a way to locate all pdf files added by the user to the files app.